# Direct access to TableLayoutPanel Cells

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TableLayoutPanel where each cell contains a single panel. I would like to be able to directly access any one of the cells by row and column and do something to the panel in it. I cannot for the life of me figure out if I can access controls within a cell. It would be great if I could do something like:

`Panel p = layoutPanel.Cell(x,y).Controls[0] as Panel;`

`p.dosomethingCool();`

But I cannot seem to get that kind of access, even though it seems like something that should be quite possible.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I found it, it is `layoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(x,y);`