# Enumerating controls within a TableLayoutPanel cell position

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

As a follow on from this question - [Direct access to TableLayoutPanel Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598620/direct-access-to-tablelayoutpanel-cells), how would one enumerate the controls within a cell in a TableLayoutPanel?  As from the picture below, I want to enumerate all the checkboxes in a given cell (so I can change their value).

[image: Example TableLayoutPanel]

I've wrote this code to try and explain what I'm trying to do (*this* being a checkbox);

```
var tableLayoutPanel = (TableLayoutPanel)this.Parent;
var cellPosition = tableLayoutPanel.GetCellPosition(this);
var controlAtPosition = tableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(cellPosition.Column,cellPosition.Row).Controls;
foreach (Control control in controlAtPosition)
{
   var ctrl = control.Name;
   // *** Enumerates nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is confusing.  Obviously, only one control is allowed in a TableLayoutPanel cell, so in your example, you have a container control holding those check boxes.

Simple example:

```
Panel p = tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(0, 0) as Panel;
if (p != null) {
  foreach (CheckBox cb in p.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) {
    MessageBox.Show(cb.Name + " " + cb.Checked.ToString());
  }
}
```