# vb TableLayoutPanel - Getting button next to the button clicked

Tags: vb.net

I created a simple TableLayoutPanel (6 by 6) with buttons in each cell. I have a click handler that executes whenever any of the button is pressed (in my case, change color of the button from red to green)

[see eg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX7HC.png)

But now I need to change the color of the button next to the button i clicked (eg. When I click on button 2 3, the button 3 3 will also change color).

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Direct access to TableLayoutPanel Cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598620/direct-access-to-tablelayoutpanel-cells)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the `Sender` argument on the click handler to a `Control` and then use that to determine the clicked control's position.  Then you can use that position to compute you adject controls and retrieve a reference to them.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ctrl As Control = TryCast(sender, Control)
    If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim pos As TableLayoutPanelCellPosition = TableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(ctrl)
        If pos.Row < (TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1) Then
            Dim nextCtrl As Control = TableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(pos.Column, pos.Row + 1)
            If nextCtrl IsNot Nothing Then
                ' do something with nextCtrl
                nextCtrl.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks man you're a lifesaver. One more question. If the column or row number is less then 0, it crashes (eg. if i click the 1 0 button, the button to the left is 1 -1 and crashes). how to fix that?

Comment: this happens when i click a button http://i.imgur.com/VKjuBzX.png ... But the corners don't work